# popup close not working with iframe content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, popup

I have created an iframe poup with the following code. Popup is loaded with iframe content. But the close button is missing.

[image]

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-iframe-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery('[data-iframe-open]').attr('data-iframe-open');
        $('[data-iframe="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(500);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //----- CLOSE
    $('[iframe-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('iframe-close');
        $('[data-iframe="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(500);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <a class="btn" data-iframe-open="popup-1" href="javascript:void(0)">click here</a>
    <div class="popup" data-iframe="popup-1">
        <div class="popup-inner">
            <iframe src="https://jquery.com/" width="100%"  height="100%" />
            <a class="iframe-close" data-iframe-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is my Css.

```
/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:26px;
    padding-top:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #DD3535;
}

.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

When I try with html content,everything works fine
http://i.prntscr.com/G3YeTkSqRr2tRFsNIWJqEw.png

How can I close my iframe popup?

Comment: Try this $('.iframe-close').click(function(){$('.popup').remove();}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your `iframe` tag.

```
<iframe src="https://jquery.com/" width="100%"  height="100%" ></iframe>
```

Change you `close` function like this:

```
//----- CLOSE
$('.iframe-close').on('click', function(e) {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).data('iframe-close');
    $('[data-iframe="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(500);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Compare this code with previous and you will find the difference.

To bring the close button style change `popup-close` to `iframe-close` in your `CSS`.

Comment: but the close html is not display

Comment: what do you mean by `close html`?

Comment: <a class="iframe-close" data-iframe-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
section is missing

Comment: Well! I think the close styling is in your style.css and you haven't showed us that. Also you styled it before adding `</iframe>` so some new styling maybe needed.

Comment: Is things ok now?

Comment: yes. now it is working. The matter is with the iframe close tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think iframe-close 
not set absolute position or 
z-index is low or
 popup over-flow hiddin or auto and (right or top) negative

iframe not Self-Closing Tag

so please use " **<iframe src="jquery.com/"; width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>**" instead of " *<iframe src="jquery.com/"; width="100%" height="100%" />*"

Comment: but the html part is missing